# Using multiple index mapping in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, multi-mapping

I`m using version 2.4.5 of elasticsearch(I need this version in project). I`ve the next lines of code:

```
  result = jestClient.execute(new PutMapping.Builder(indexName, Types.USER, userMappingSource).build());
  ...
  result = jestClient.execute(new PutMapping.Builder(indexName, Types.FOLLOWER, followerMappingSource).build());
```

The project code was wrote that consistently mapping two mapping files to one index (code above).
When I`m using existing code I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't add a _parent field that points to an already existing type, that isn't already a parent
```

I can fixed it transfer field index to another file. But, I would have error in Java code. How could I fix it?